# How do i collect multiple messages from service bus topic using logic app

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Basically I just want one single instance of logic app to collect multiple message (5 messages at a time), So I can build an array of messages to process once.

Comment: Try using `Get messages form a topic subscription (peek lock)` connector, you can set no. of messages to read. Let me know if this helps, I will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Harshita said, you could use `Get messages form a topic subscription (peek lock)` and set the `Maximum message count` with 5.

[image]

And the output is as below. The message we sent to topic encode with `base64` will be `ContentData`.
[image]

Comment: yes, this would pickup multiple messages but process them as separate LA instances